# mySQL private/conn issues

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having some issues with a 1&1 account a client of mine is hosted with.
I'm getting errors on lines 2 & 20 (denoted as bold below), which doesn't make sense as they're basic php functions.

I've used this same script dozens of times with no issues, until putting it on this 1&1 account. Is anyone seeing something I may be missing?

```
class Mysql 
{
  private $conn;

  function __construct() 
  {
    $this->conn = new mysqli(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME) or 
       die('There was a problem connecting to the database.');
  }

  function verify_Username_and_Pass($un, $pwd) 
  {  
    $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ? AND password = ? LIMIT 1";

    if ($stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query)) {
      $stmt->bind_param('ss', $un, $pwd);
      $stmt->execute();
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

thanks pinkgothic for reminding me to put the errors on here >.<

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting T_OLD_FUNCTION or T_FUNCTION or T_VAR or '}' in /homepages/24/d100728/htdocs/members/classes/Mysql.php on line 6
```

^thats for the private class

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function on a non-object in /homepages/24/d100728/htdocs/members/classes/Mysql.php on line 20
```

^when the private line is commented out, im able to reach the login screen but get this error on submission.

Also, the database is running MySQL5.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If its failing on the private variable declaration, it could be running PHP 4, as there was no way to make private class properties til PHP 5.

Comment: your right, thats what it was. they still have the server at PHP Version 4.4.9. is there a workaround for this?

Comment: @Nick: You mean "aside from rewriting the code to downgrade it to PHP 4?" Not really.

Comment: Well, it may or may not work. But you can change the private to say var. And PHP4 also doesn't support the __construct method.  The old way was to make a function with the same name of the class for the constructor.  So change __contstruct to Mysql.

Comment: thanks for your help guys. after searching through obscure help pages in their 'knowledgebase', i found out they do offer PHP 5 access, you just have to rename all your files to .php5.